# What is the prefered method to install Python with Ansible on CentOS 8

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, centos8

CentOS 8 does not always come with Python pre-installed, and so Ansible will fail running on the remote machine until it's been installed.  However in a classic Chicken/Egg, you can't use the Ansible `dnf` module to install Python.

I've been using:

```
- name: Install Python 3
  raw: dnf -y install python3
```

However the problem with this is that I either have to set `changed_when: false` or it will always return a changed state. I'd like the state reported properly if it's possible.

I found `easy_install` however this appears to only deal with Python Libraries, and not Python itself.  Is there a built-in way to handle this or is `raw:` the only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it goes, there is no simple answer, the truth is that if Python is not installed, the only method to get it installed with Ansible is to use the `raw:` method.  Here is the answer I was provided at ServerFault... https://serverfault.com/questions/1016870/what-is-the-prefered-method-to-install-python-with-ansible-on-centos-8

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. CentOS 8 comes with platform-python out of the box, which Ansible >= 2.8 will use by default.

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/14/python-in-rhel-8-3

https://www.ansible.com/blog/integrating-ansible-and-red-hat-enterprise-linux-8-beta

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html

Happy automating!

Comment: The first link contains "In RHEL 8, Python 3.6 is the default, fully supported version of Python. It is not always installed, however. Similarly to any other available tool, use yum install python3 to get it.", the second link is dead, and the third is how to auto locate or specify a interpreter.

Comment: Above comment is not correct, platform-python is always installed for REHL 8 to support system tools (`dnf` which is written in python wouldn't work otherwise,) and is selected by default by versions of Ansible >= 2.8. See also https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1670188